# parallel NAND flash dumped with dd mtd0-12

Tags: linux

Hi hope some one can help i have tried dumping nand on a system in u-boot with the dd command so i have mtd0-12 but have now messed up bootloader now i have non booting device/brick. i have tried jtag but was a no go atm. i am new to Linux so is there any way of converting mtd0-12 to one bin file so i can flash nand off of the pcb or will i have ecc problems any input is welcome thank you.